# Preserving Hausdorff property

Tags: general-topology

Let $X\ \&\ Y$ are topological spaces and $\text{~}$ is an equivalence relation on X. Consider the following maps.
$f: X\to Y$, when $Y$ is Hausdorff.
$g: X\to Y$, when $X$ is Hausdorff.
$f: X\to X/\text{~}$, where $X$ is Hausdorff.
Provide conditions on $f,g,h$ so that the other space is also Hausdorff.

My approach.

Clearly homeomorphism does this. Now we find some stronger conditions.
If $Y$ is Hausdorff and $f$ is injective, continuous then we are done. As say $x,y \in X$, then $f(x) ,f(y)$ are different and hence there exists $U_x,U_y$ containing $x,y$ respectively so that both are open and disjoint. Since f is continuous, $f^{-1}(U_x)$ and $f^{-1}(U_y)$ are both open and disjoint, $x\in f^{-1}(U_x)$ and $y \in f^{-1}(U_x)$. Hence X is Hausdorff.

For the second question, if $f$ is open and surjective, we should be done. As if $x,y \in Y$, then there are $u,v\in X$ so that $f(u)=x,f(v)=y $. Now use Hausdorff property in X to find open sets and through the open map $f$, send open sets to open sets.

I guess these logics work. Any thing more to add.
And any idea for the third one.

Comment: For the second question: I'm confused, you assume that $Y$ is Hausdorff in $f$ case. Obviously $X$ need not be Hausdorff when $f$ is only open and surjective. The easiest counterexample is $X\to\{*\}$ for any non-Hausdorff $X$. If you meant "second answer" for case $g$, i.e. when we assume that $X$ is Hausdorff then your reasoning is wrong. How do you know that $u\neq v$ in order to separated them? And even if they were, how do you know that images of those neighbourhoods don't intersect?

Comment: No, $g$ open and surjective and even continuous is not enough. Under those 3 assumptions we have that $Y$ is Hausdorff if and only if $\text{ker}(g)=\{(x,x')\ |\ g(x)=g(x')\}$ is a closed subspace of $X\times X$. I encourage you to find a counterexample.

Comment: @freakish I got the point. There is no guarantee that image sets won't intersect